# ERROR: 'abc' does not have a name type QT c++ GUI application

Tags: c++, forms, qt, user-interface

bottom line is i have 2 forms , first mainwindow 2nd form1 . i have a button on mainwindow that displays form 2 . now i have a button on form1 that should take me to mainwindow but it is not working. problem is when i say #include  in form1.h it gives me an error i.e mainwindow does not have a name type. please help , working example would be great if possible . Actual error is MainWindow does not have a name type

mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <form1.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;   // i put this line of code in public section when i was trying ui->show(); in form1.cpp file 

    Form1 obj ; // to show next form

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        obj.show();
        this->hide();
    }
```

Form1.h

```
  #ifndef FORM1_H
#define FORM1_H
#include <QWidget>

#include<mainwindow.h>

namespace Ui {
    class Form1;
}

class Form1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Form1 *ui;

    MainWindow mw ;     // here i am making object of main window
};

#endif // FORM1_H
```

form1.cpp

```
#include "form1.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"

#include<mainwindow.h>   // i know when i include this there this issue occurs , but i want to go my previous form to show and for that i have to make its object ! thats how it works when i am going to my next form i.e form1 now i want to go back 



Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),

ui(new Ui::Form1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form1::~Form1()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form1::on_pushButton_clicked() // show mainWindow
{
    mw->show();
    this->hide();
    //MainWindow::ui->show();        // i even tried this
}
```

i also tried if i could do it without including mainwindow.h in form1.h by puttin Ui::MainWindow *ui; in public section so form1.cpp file i could access it by typing MainWindow::ui->show(); this time ERROR says Object is missing Reference to 'MainWindow::ui'

Comment: `mainWindow.h`? Some operating systems use case sensitive names (most \*nix ones), so that can lead to trouble. Also, post the exact error.

Comment: @zeta , this is the ERROR : 'mainWindow' does not have a name type

Comment: @Zeta you can see the code . IDE generates mainwindow's form automatically as it is the first form . so i dont think so that case sensitive is the real probem. i just tried all    #include<MainWindow.h> , #include<Mainwindow.h> #include<mainWindow.h> and #include<mainwindow.h> no use :( ! Zeta Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Zeta and i tried them in form.h

Comment: Add additional information to your question, not in comments. Make sure your question can be easily understood. Currently it's more or less a wall of code. Try to cut it down to the essentials (also, at this point, I'm trying to improve your question, not answer it; that would be an answer, not a comment :D).

Comment: @Zeta sorry this is my first question on any forum :)

Comment: HAHAHAHA People help please xD

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency between the classes `MainWindow` and `Form1`. Thus, you include `form1.h` in `mainwindow.h` and `mainwindow.h` in `form1.h`. When the compiler reaches the line

```
MainWindow mw ;     // here i am making object of main window
```

it is the first time he encounters the symbol `MainWindow` and trigger that error.

I still don't understand why `mw` is a  member of Form1, but you can break the dependency using a pointer instead. Basically you will now have

```
MainWindow* mw ;
```

And rather than `#include<mainwindow.h>` in `Form1.h` you will just have to forward declare

```
class MainWindow;
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer :) 
i am trying to implement for a while but it is not working

Comment: Thankyou for your answer :) 
 why mw is a member of Form1 , well because there is a button on form1 Form and behind that button i want to write a code that will show mainwindow Form and for that i will have to make object of mainwindow in form1.h so in form1.cpp i could use it .  
i am trying to implement for a while but it is not working it is giving another ERROR : request for member 'show' in '((Form1*)this)->Form1::mw' , which is of non-class type 'MainWindow*'